# OrganizationRequestParameters tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

Where is a good tutorial/guide on how to use the parameters for a C# CRM SDK OrganizationRequest parameter collection?

Here's my code so far:

```
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse("hidden");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(connection);

OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest("requestname");
/* ... ? */
```

How would I modify `request` so when I execute it with `service` I get the number of contacts?

Comment: yep. [characters for sufficient response length]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [OrganizationRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequest_members) class description, it was not designed to work directly with this class, but you can if you want.

> You can use this class, specifying the parameter collection. However,
>   when you use the derived class, the parameter collection is created
>   for you.

Actually you should specify not only parameter collection, but also request name. Full list of available request names was provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequest.requestname). Depending what request name you need you should specify appropriate parameters collection. Actually there is no complete reference for parameters collection.
Another question is how to retrieve count of contacts. Here you have two options. The first one is not related to OrganizationRequest, but you have to use organization context and linq queries. Sample was described [here](http://www.resultondemand.nl/support/sdk/43b26b09-636e-4781-8477-65454c4c5232.htm). Another option is using of [ExecuteFetch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959412.aspx) message request name.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is a reference itself!